# How to run batch jobs in Matlab using parcluster, if I want to run a method of a class

Tags: matlab

I want to run jobs in Matlab using batch, with parcluster. each job should use an existing class, and run one of it's methods. I can make It work without parcluster, but with parcluster I get an error.

without parpool, this works:

define a class with a simple method:

```
classdef myclass
    properties
        prop;
    end
    methods
        % constructor
        function obj = myclass()
             obj.prop = 0;
        end
        % add function 
        function obj = add(obj,a)
            obj.prop = obj.prop + a;
        end
    end
end
```

create an object and use it's function:

```
obj = myclass();
obj = add(obj,1);
```

this works. but when I try to run the same thing in batch I get an error. here is what I'm doing:

```
c = parcluster();
j = batch(c,@myclass,1,{});
wait(j);
r = fetchOutputs(j);
obj = r{1};
j = batch(c,@add,1,{obj,1});
```

the last line gives an error:

> warning unable to calculate the dependencies of the files:
>   add
>    because: file, function or class "add" may not exist.

how can I run class methods in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust way of specifying a method of a class in an anonymous function is to use the dot notation

```
B = batch(c, @obj.add, 1, {1});

wait(B)

%// Re-assign results to obj (see note below)
obj = fetchOutputs(B);
```

This helps MATLAB to resolve `myclass.add` better as it is more explicit. The way that you had written it previously, MATLAB is looking for a regular function named `add` and is unable to find it. It does not consider the types of the input (which in your case would be required to know that it is a method).

> Note: `batch` will make a *copy* of your object when you pass it as an input. Because of that, you will need to explicitly grab the output and re-assign to `obj` because the original `obj` *will not* be modified in-place.